# Swiftコンパイラの環境構築の際、utils/update-checkout --cloneでコケてしまいます。

Tags: python, swift, c++, macos, swift5

macOS10.15.1にて、Swiftの最新のソースをcloneしてSwiftコンパイラの環境構築をしようとしています。

ドキュメント通り`swift/utils/update-checkout --clone`を実行した所、以下のエラーメッセージが出て止まってしまいました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/update-checkout", line 5, in <module>
    import update_checkout
  File "/Users/user/src/swift-source/swift/utils/update_checkout/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from update_checkout import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'update_checkout' (/Users/user/src/swift-source/swift/utils/update_checkout/__init__.py)
```

エラー文で検索してみるとpipが壊れている可能性があるということで以下コマンドで再インストールしてみましたが、うまく行かず。そもそもpipでインストールしたものをimportしようとしているわけではないので、それはそうという気がします、、、

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

どなたかここをクリアする術をご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: `apt` は別OS (Ubuntu/Debian) のコマンドなので、macOSの環境でどのような手順を実施したのかを記載しておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick  コメントありがとうございます！編集します。